# Docker container/image running but there is no port number

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to get a django project that I have built to run on docker and create an image and container for my project so that I can push it to my dockerhub profile.

Now I have everything set up and I've created the initial image of my project. However, when I run it I am not getting any port number attached to the container. I need this to test and see if the container is actually working.

Here is what I have:

```
Successfully built a047506ef54b
Successfully tagged test_1:latest
(MySplit) omars-mbp:mysplit omarjandali$ docker images
REPOSITORY                    TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
test_1                        latest              a047506ef54b        14 seconds ago      810MB

(MySplit) omars-mbp:mysplit omarjandali$ docker run --name testing_first -d -p 8000:80 test_1
01cc8173abfae1b11fc165be3d900ee0efd380dadd686c6b1cf4ea5363d269fb

(MySplit) omars-mbp:mysplit omarjandali$ docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
01cc8173abfa        test_1              "python manage.py ru…"   13 seconds ago      Exited (1) 11 seconds ago                       testing_first
(MySplit) omars-mbp:mysplit omarjandali$ Successfully built a047506ef54b
```

You can see there is no port number so I don't know how to access the container through my local machine on my web browser.

dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR tab/
COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Comment: `Exited (1) 11 seconds ago` - you may need to check the docker logs, as this looks (at least to me) that something prevented django from starting properly. The ports were probably freed when the django process exited.

Comment: Can we see the `Dockerfile`? Make sure your Dockerfile has the line `EXPOSE 80`

Comment: @JabariDash The EXPOSE directive shouldn't actually matter in this case - he has forwarded the port on the command line. I think the docker logs are definitely going to be more interesting.

Comment: @Shadow That's fair. I wasn't aware that port forward on the command like made it actually expose the port too. Good to know. In that case, you are probably right. The application is failing in some way.

Comment: how do i check the docker logs... @Shadow

Comment: If i want to put the expose in the docker file instead of having to enter the port in the run command where would i put it... @JabariDash

Comment: @OmarJandali `docker logs <container_id>` (in your example, `docker logs 01cc817` should do the trick) or even lazier, drop the `-d` and run it inline.

Comment: where do i find the docker server url/name @Shadow to see the url on my web browser

Comment: when i run `docker run -p 8000:80 test_3` shouldnt it give me a url of some sort with an extension for the docker conatiner that is running.. it is is not doing anything. it is just gives me a blank line without anything... it normally displays the following `System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 02, 2018 - 03:55:30
Django version 2.0.2, using settings 'mysplit.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.` I am not getting that here @Shadow

Comment: Sounds like an issue with stream buffering... Try `CMD ["python" "-u" "manage.py"` etc. This should disable it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line from the question helps reveal the problem;

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
01cc8173abfa        test_1              "python manage.py ru…"   13 seconds ago      Exited (1) 11 seconds ago                       testing_first
```

`Exited (1)` (from the STATUS column) means that the main process has already exited with a status code of 1 - usually meaning an error. This would have freed up the ports, as the docker container stops running when the main process finishes for any reason.

[You need to view the logs in order to diagnose why.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/)

`docker logs 01cc` will show the logs of the docker container that has the ID starting with `01cc`. You should find that reading these will help you on your way. Knowing this command will help you immensely in debugging weirdness in docker, whether the container is running or stopped.

An alternative 'quick' way is to drop the `-d` in your run command. This will make your container run inline rather than as a daemon.

Comment: I got the following: `CommandError: "0.0.0.0" is not a valid port number or address:port pair.`

Comment: Then you have your answer. Your CMD is wrong. You probably meant to write `CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]`

Comment: I create and ran a new image of my project with the addition you suggested and when i tried ot run it i got the folllowng: 
`Run a command in a new container
(MySplit) omars-mbp:mysplit omarjandali$ docker run test_2
usage: manage.py runserver [-h] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}]
                           [--settings SETTINGS] [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH]
                           [--traceback] [--no-color] [--ipv6] [--nothreading]
                           [--noreload] [--nostatic] [--insecure]
                           [addrport]
manage.py runserver: error: unrecognized arguments: 8000`

Comment: Yeah, I made a typo in the command. Fixed it now. Also don't let the fact that django is running in docker distract you - it still will behave the same way as if you were running it outside of docker.

Comment: None of that matters until the process is actually working (but your command was right the first time with the `-p8000:80`)

Comment: So now it is running. how can i see if it is working trough my browser: `ONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS                  NAMES
7932e349bb95        test_3              "python manage.py ru…"   3 seconds ago        Up 5 seconds                    0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp   eager_babbage` it shows the port but what do i put in the url

Comment: The address of your docker server.

Comment: so i have to push it to docker him and then put the link in.... @Shadow

Comment: where do i find the docker server url

Answer (score 2):

When you created the container you published the ports. Your container would be accessible via port 8000 if it successfully built. However, as [Shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1594286/shadow) pointed out, your container exited with an error. That is why you must add the `-a` flag to your `docker container ls` command. `docker container ls` only shows running containers without the `-a` flag.

I recommend forgoing the detached flag `-d` to see what is causing the error. Then creating a new container after you have successfully launched the one you are working on. Or simply run the following commands once you fix the issue. `docker stop testing_first` then `docker container rm testing_first` finally run the same command you ran before. `docker run --name testing_first -d -p 8000:80 test_1`

I ran into similar problems with the first docker instances I attempted to run as well.

Answer (score 2):

## Created Dockerise django seed project

```
django-admin.py startproject djangoapp
```

## Need a requirements.txt file outlining the Python dependencies

```
cd djangoapp/
```

## RUN follwoing command to create the files required for dockerization

```
cat <<EOF > requirements.txt
Django
psycopg2
EOF
```

## Dockerfile

```
cat <<EOF > Dockerfile

FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /app/

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
EOF
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
cat <<EOF > docker-compose.yml

version: "3.2"    
services:
  web:
    image: djangoapp
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
EOF
```

## Run the application with

```
docker-compose up -d
```